# VNC with RedHat 7.0

Tags: redhat, vnc

I am having troubles with VNC for connection to RH 7.0 from W7.

My connection cannot be established as the connection times out every time.

I am unfamiliar with the RH 7 GUI and cannot seem to find the VNC preferences anywhere. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked `firewalld` logs, AVC denials, `journalctl` output?

Comment: Do you really mean Red Hat 7.0 (which is some 15 years ancient now)?

Comment: I have not... I went to disable the firewall, as I do not need it in my environment however I can't figure out how to... I tried stopping via `chkconfig iptables off` ect... but I get a rerouting message.

Comment: I have RH release 7.0 (Maipo)